# Javascript Using array to populate select option

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, select

My code does not populate anything but leave the select menu empty.

Here is my html

```
<select id="parent" onChange="displayExample();"></select>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
/* array of option values */
var POPULATING_ARRAY = [ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" ];
var parent = document.getElementById("namedOfSelect");

for ( var pos = 0; pos < POPULATING_ARRAY.length; pos++)
{
    //create an <option> to add the <select>
    var child = document.createElement("option");

    //assign values to the <option>
    child.textContent = POPULATING_ARRAY[pos]
    child.value = pos;

    //attach the mew <option> to the <selection>
    parent.appendChild(child);
}

function displayExample()
{
    var current = document.getElementById("parent");
    var op = parseInt(current.value);
    document.getElementById("helpMsg").innerText = EXAMPLES[op];    
}
```

The code is supposed to programmatically add the options to the select from the JavaScript.

Comment: what is `Examples` array ? Any reason why There is no code inside `displayExample()` to add options to the select item?

Comment: What happens when you debug the code? For instance, what happens if you put a breakpoint after the `var parent=` line, and check the value of `parent`?

Comment: What do you REALLY want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID that you mentioned in your 2nd line in Javascript is wrong.

Change it to:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fojzgacd/)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = (function(){
  addOptions();
})(); 
function addOptions(){
  var items = [ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" ];                 
  for (i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    var x = document.getElementById("parent");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = items[i];
    x.add(option,x[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace the "namedOfSelect" by you select Id "parent"

Here is the working
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/ozgx68kx/)

Answer (score 0):

why u have to get values from javascript you can directly get it from using  in html

```
<select id="parent" onChange="displayExample();">
    <option>Item1</option>
    <option>Item2</option>
    <option>Item3</option>
</select>
```